# How to bypass MAC address filters

Tags: windows, mac-address, spoofing

I have a program that gets my MAC address, and it won't work with the real one; I need to clone it. The problem is that if i try to spoof it from `regedit`, the software will recognize it. I cannot use another program. Is there any other way to change the MAC address??

Answer (score 3):

When you say `regedit` I'm assuming you are on a Windows system.

The official way to change the MAC, if the driver supports it, is through Start -> Run -> ncpa.cpl -> right click the adapter and select Properties -> click Configure -> and if the NIC driver supports changing the MAC, a page with the appropriate option will be there.  Some Wifi drivers do not support changing the MAC.  I believe this effectively/safely modifies the registry in a manner consistent with what Windows and the NIC driver in question expect.

Now, I had an onboard Wifi that did not present such an option.  And [SMAC](http://www.klcconsulting.net/smac/) would not work either.  However, [macshift](http://devices.natetrue.com/macshift/) worked great, however, note that this utility is only for WIndows XP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to change the en0 address on a Macintosh machine you can try the following

```
sudo ifconfig en0 lladdr 11:22:33:44:55:66
```

Or

```
sudo ifconfig en0 ether 11:22:33:44:55:66
```

The address you choose is up to you. Your MAC address will be reset on reboot.

If you want to test to see if the change took place you could try one of the following commands.

```
netstat -I en0 | egrep -o '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'

ifconfig en0 | egrep -o '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'

ifconfig | sed -n '/en0\:/,/status\:/p' | grep "ether" | sed "s:ether::g" | sed "s:[[:space:]]::g"
```

NOTE: 'egrep -o' works like 'grep -o -E'

If you want to switch back to your original MAC address prior to reboot you can obtain your original MAC address and switch the MAC address back with the following steps.

STEP 1

```
system_profiler SPNetworkDataType | awk '$2 == "Ethernet", $1 == "MAC"' |  awk '$1 == "Ethernet:", $1 == "MAC"' | egrep -o '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

STEP 2

```
sudo ifconfig en0 ether "YOUR ORIGINAL MAC ADDRESS OBTAINED BY STEP 1"
```

STEP 3

```
sudo ifconfig en0 down
```

STEP 4

```
sudo ifconfig en0 up
```

Comment: oops I did not see that the question was specific to Windows prior to post.